# Использование конструктора абстрактного класса

Tags: java

Всем привет!

В общем есть абстрактный родительский класс, в котором объявлены все необходимые переменные и абстрактный метод.
Два класса-наследника лишь по разному реализуют логику этого метода оперируя одинаковыми унаследованными переменными.

При этом в абстрактном классе прописан конструктор принимающий данные для инициализации всех переменных класса. Конструкторы с такой же сигнатурой есть и в наследниках, где они попросту перенаправляют свои входящие данные на конструктор `super(...)`.

Так вот, все работает хорошо, вот только есть сомнение, что как-то не по фен-шую эти конструкторы сделаны как оптимизировать?

Comment: Вполне по фен-шую. Если включать в базовый класс какую-либо логику вы не собираетесь, то можете просто заменить его на интерфейс.

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под оптимизацией? Что именно, по вашему мнению, нуждается в улучшении? Какой параметр?

Comment: @andreycha Спасибо за ответ! Выбор сделан в пользу абстрактного класса, а не интерфейса, чтобы не дублировать в наследниках N строк с объявлением полей, их геттерами и сеттерами. Классы полностью идентичны по своей сути, разница только в логике ключевого метода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я понял, у вас примерно следующая ситуация:

```
abstract class A {

    private int value;

    public A(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public abstract void print();
}

class B extends A {

    public B(int value) {
        super(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("B: " + getValue());
    }

}

class C extends A {

    public C(int value) {
        super(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("C: " + getValue());
    }

}
```

Основная причина для создания новых классов - разное поведение метода.
Если вы вынесете этот метод в функциональный интерфейс, то все равно вам придется объявлять два класса с транзитными конструкторами (которые вызывают super).

К тому же в любом случае вам придется добавлять конструктор, если родительский конструктор содержит параметры. Только конструкторы без параметров вызываются автоматически.

Таким образом, если идти по пути наследования, то вариант только один - инициализировать параметры через методы уже после создания объекта, т.е. не в конструкторе. Это можно делать как вручную, так и использовать какой-нибудь паттерн.

Другой вариант - не делать несколько классов, а использовать изначальный класс, который абстрактный, т.е. сделать его не абстрактным, а ему в качестве параметра передавать реализацию того самого метода.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да, ситуация примерно такая, только класс С тоже переопределяет абстрактный метод, но по другому. Ну и переменных (они же параметры конструктора), чуть больше. Архитектура такова, что должны быть именно класс В и класс С, с разной реализацией ключевого метода, в остальном же они полностью идентичны. Исходя из этого, я и решил вынести общую часть в абстрактный класс и затем использовать наследование, тем более, что теперь удобнее хранить все в коллекции по родительскому классу. А насчет транзитного конструктора не знаю чего засомневался...неопытность и 6 час кодинга за полночь

Answer (score 1):

По фэн шую, конструктор абстрактного класса должен быть `protected`, то есть:

```
abstract class A {

    private int value;

    protected A(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public abstract void print();
}
```